# how to get current position in ARCore?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, arcore

I'm making a hide-and-seek game app with Android studio. So my application needs to know the location information of each player's device (no coordinates are required, like GPS).
At first, this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?We tried to create IMUs using acceleration sensors, gyroscopes and geomagnetic sensors like v=6ijArKE8vKU), but after searching and finding out in many ways, we decided to do it in a different way.
So the way I'm thinking now is to collect the current location of each player with the information from ARCore's Concurrent Odometry and Mapping Process.
However, most documents and tutorials seem to start with the object placement, anchor part.
How can I get the current player's location in ARCore or the motion tracking information on my device?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FirstPersonCamera.transform.position to get the current x y z position of your device in current scene